# Codeigniter MySQL Join Complex

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have several tables which would like to show in a one time with one id.

### Table A

id | isi a1 | isi a2

### Table B

id | id_a | isi b1 | isi b2

### Table C

id | id_a | isi c1 | isi c2

### Table D

id | id_a | isi d1 | isi d2

### Table E

id | id_a | isi e1 | isi e2

I'd like to show isi B1-E2 which each table have id_a = id in table A. I have no idea with mysql join, I've try this code

```
$this->db->select('BaseTbl.id, BaseTbl.tanggal, BaseTbl.atas_nama, BaseTbl.kerugian, BaseTbl.keterangan, BaseTbl.admin, BaseTbl.status');
$this->db->from('data_blacklist as BaseTbl');
$this->db->join('bl_rekening as Rekening, bl_telefon as Telefon, bl_bukti as Bukti, bl_pelapor as Pelapor', 'Rekening.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id, Telefon.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id, Bukti.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id, Pelapor.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id','left');
```

but its always give me

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' bl_telefon as Telefon, bl_bukti as Bukti, bl_pelapor as Pelapor ON `Rekening`.`' at line 3
```

I have no idea at this time. Any idea? I use codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You have to query join for each table. You can't combine them

```
$this->db->select('BaseTbl.id, BaseTbl.tanggal, BaseTbl.atas_nama, BaseTbl.kerugian, BaseTbl.keterangan, BaseTbl.admin, BaseTbl.status');
$this->db->from('data_blacklist as BaseTbl',);
$this->db->join('bl_rekening as Rekening','Rekening.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id','left');
$this->db->join('bl_telefon as Telefon','Telefon.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id','left');
$this->db->join('bl_bukti as Bukti','Bukti.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id','left');
$this->db->join('bl_pelapor as Pelapor','Pelapor.id_blacklist = BaseTbl.id','left');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.*');
        $this->db->from( TABLES::$A . ' AS a' );
        $this->db->join(TABLES::$B .  ' AS b', 'a.id = b.id_a');
        $this->db->join(TABLES::$C .  ' AS c', 'a.id = c.id_a');
        $this->db->join(TABLES::$D .  ' AS d', 'a.id = d.id_a');
        $this->db->join(TABLES::$E .  ' AS e', 'a.id = e.id_a');

        $query=$this->db->get();
        //  echo $this->db->last_query();
        $result = $query->result_array();

        return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you to do in a manual query in CodeIgniter.

```
return $this->db->query("select A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*, E.* from Table A, Table B, Table C, Table D, Table E WHERE A.id = B.id_a AND A.id = C.id_a AND A.id = D.id_a AND A.id = E.id_a")->result_array();
```

A,B,C,D and E are alias name of the table. It will bring you data if values exist. Or you can also write manual query